# IF A1 has content - run macroA Else do nothing ...?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button signed to a Macro, However if cell `A1` has no content I get the debug error (runs via that)

I was wondering, as title says.. Can I run a IF command with a Macro?

So, If `Sheet1!A1 = ANY content` (differs from time to time) `THEN run macroA`

`IF Sheet1!A1 = no content THEN do nothing` (button just does nothing)

Possible?

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1")) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "A1 is empty"
        Else
        Application.Run "Macro2()" 'edit macro name to suit
    End If
End Sub
```

Not quite `do nothing` - displays a warning of why nothing (much) happened. But comment out the MsgBox line if you prefer.

Comment: + 1 Another ex would be `If len(trim(Range("A1")))=0 then`

Comment: or If IsEmpty(range("A1")) then ... or trim(range("A1"))=""... for me calling a worksheet function to do the job is the worst approach... :)

Comment: @pnuts In that sense I agree 100%... :)